# is it posible to add two backpress event in same activity in android

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I am working on simple project and at some point am stuck.in my activity am using dialog box. I want to add `backpressed()` event on dialog box and whole activity.but when I add 2 same method it shows me error.

Comment: you can manually handle the back buttons then .

Comment: you can finish the dialog box containing activity

Comment: If dialog visible close the dialog or close the activity.

Comment: You should show some code....post please what You have tried....and post the stacktrace..

Comment: i do not want to  perform operation on dialog box still it has to be go back.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1):

First make dialogbox object globally then `onbackpressed()` method, check if dialog is showing or not using `isShowing()` method. if it returns true then dismiss that dialog and if not showing then perform your other operation on else part.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     if(dialog.isShowing()){
         dialog.dismiss();
     }else{
         super.onBackPressed();
     }

}
```